# Qual è il significato di "assottigliare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Rinascimento privato* di Maria Bellonci ho letto:

> Quando il mio pensiero si raccoglie in voi ho pace e guerra insieme e mi ricordo di essere poeta col rammarico di non esserlo abbastanza. Il mio coraggio si **assottiglia** se mi dico che forse leggerete queste righe e, impaziente, alzerete gli occhi lampeggianti domandandovi "che cosa vuole costui?". Niente, illustre Signora, anzi meno che niente perché so di non poter essere perdonato di quel mio stolto inganno che mi ha reso per tanto tempo disagiato pronunciare persino tra me e me il vostro nome.

Non capisco il significato di "assottigliare" in questo brano. Ho cercato questo verbo nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/assottigliare) e ho visto che può avere due sensi figurati diversi:

> **2**. fig. **a**. Ridurre, scemare di quantità, di volume: *a. le spese; le rendite si sono assottigliate*. **b**. Riferito alle facoltà intellettuali, affinare, rendere più acuto, più perspicace: *a. la mente, l’ingegno, il cervello; le tribolazioni aguzzano il cervello: e Renzo ... non s’era mai trovato nell’occasione d’assottigliar molto il suo* (Manzoni). Nell’uso ant. anche rifl., *assottigliarsi*, assottigliare l’ingegno, impegnarsi con acutezza di mente in un’interpretazione e sim.: *piglia Quel ch’io ti dicerò ... E intorno da esso t’assottiglia* (Dante); *Filocolo ... cominciasi a crucciare e a tignersi nel viso, e assottigliarsi se potesse il giuoco per maestria recuperare* (Boccaccio).

Quindi, il mio dubbio è: nel passaggio di sopra significa diminuire oppure rendere più acuto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A prima vista può sembrare ambiguo, ma la riflessività del verbo e il fatto che "il coraggio" sia il soggetto (*), assicurano che il significato è il primo che hai riportato. Avevo scritto la risposta di fretta e non ci avevo fatto caso, ma in effetti qui è fondamentale osservare che l'accezione simile ad *acuire* riguarda solo qualità assimilabili all'**intelligenza**, e il coraggio non lo è.

D'altronde, le opzioni erano il rafforzamento del coraggio o il sopraggiungere della paura, e il pensiero degli *occhi lampeggianti* e il tono autocommiserativo dell'ultima frase, non possono che essere correlati alla paura.

(*) Da notare che l'antico uso riflessivo, nella seconda accezione, ha come soggetto la persona, non la qualità della stessa, analogamente ad *ingegnarsi*:  *il castellano cominciasi a crucciare… e assottigliarsi se potesse il giuoco per maestria recuperare* (Boccaccio).